# "ffmpeg" set fontsize and font

Tags: ffmpeg, filter, linux

Im trying to set font and font size but i can use only one of the filters not both here is mine command

```
ffmpeg -i movie.avi -strict -2 -vf subtitles=subtile.srt:force_style='FontName=ubuntu, Fontsize=30' -qscale:v 3 out.avi
```

but I get

```
No such filter: 'Fontsize'
```

But if I set just Fontsize it works just fine, any help ? TNX in advance

Answer (score 3):

I did solved this with " "

```
"subtitles=subtitle.srt:force_style='FontName=ubuntu,Fontsize=30'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space.

```
ffmpeg -i movie.avi -strict -2 -vf subtitles=subtile.srt:force_style='FontName=ubuntu,Fontsize=30' -qscale:v 3 out.avi
```

Comment: Tnx for quick reply but Iv got same error 
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x1f56f20] No such filter: 'Fontsize'

Comment: This is a matter of which quote marks you're using. If I use double quotes, I get the same error. With single quotes, it works. Is your command run from inside a batch file?

Comment: No its not its command line Im getting error and I using single quotes TNX

Comment: Show the full console output.

Comment: Here you go http://pastebin.com/GWT0YMtW

Comment: Try escaping the single quotes. This is really a shell-related Q, not ffmpeg.

Comment: I did tried without '' but same dial filter error

Comment: Try my command on another OS or setup if you can.

Comment: In my shell I had to escape the comma: `ffmpeg -i movie.avi -strict -2 -vf subtitles=subtile.srt:force_style='FontName=ubuntu\,Fontsize=30' -qscale:v 3 out.avi`